# Is there a way to get a current index or filename with interactiveStyleMPRSlice in vtk.js?

Tags: itk, vtk.js

I cloned vue-vtkjs-viewport and trying to get index to overlay a labeled image when scrolling (dcm/0.dcm <-> label/0.png).

https://kitware.github.io/vtk-js/api/Interaction_Style_InteractorStyleMPRSlice.html

In the official kitware github, there is a way to get slice but the slice shows strange number as -510.0123 and the sliceRange is [-758.2000122070312, -236.20001220703125].

I uploaded 50 dicom files and i wanted to get a current index or filename.
Is there any way to get the information?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Both [ITK](https://discourse.itk.org/t/solved-transformindextophysicalpoint-manually/1031) and [VTK](https://discourse.vtk.org/t/how-to-convert-the-coordinate-between-pixel-and-physical-vtkimagereslice/1391) have a way to transform physical point to index, which is probably what you want.